# Disabling ListBox on Page_Load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to disable the two list boxes on load of my web form, but the list boxes are not disabling. I tried the code below but it's still not working on my case. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

DESIGNER CODE

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="lbSelectedDepartmentContacts" runat="server" Width="220px" AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true" AutoPostBackOnReorder="true" AutoPostBackOnDelete="true" CheckBoxes="false" AllowTransfer="true" AllowTransferOnDoubleClick="true" TransferToID="lbDepartmentContacts"
                                                                            Height="276px" SelectionMode="Single" AllowReorder="True">
                                                                            <ButtonSettings ShowTransfer="false" ShowTransferAll="false" ReorderButtons="Common" ShowReorder="true" />
                                                                        </telerik:RadListBox>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="right">
                                                                        <telerik:RadListBox ID="lbDepartmentContacts" runat="server" Width="200px" CheckBoxes="false" AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true" AllowTransfer="true" AllowTransferOnDoubleClick="true" TransferToID="lbSelectedDepartmentContacts"
                                                                            Height="250px" SelectionMode="Single">
                                                                            <ButtonSettings TransferButtons="Common" ShowTransfer="false" ShowTransferAll="false" />
                                                                        </telerik:RadListBox>
```

BACKCODE

```
public void DisableControls()
        {
 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>function DisableControls(){");
            sb.Append(@"var lbl = document.getElementById('lbSelectedDepartmentContacts').disabled = true;");
            sb.Append(@" var Txt = document.getElementById('txtDepartmentCategoryContactsFilter').disabled = true;");
            sb.Append(@" var btn = document.getElementById('RadButton1').disabled = true;");

            sb.Append("}</script>");

            if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock"))
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock",
                sb.ToString());
            }

            string funcCall = "<script language='javascript'>DisableControls();</script>";

            if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", funcCall);
            } 
}
```

Tried Also:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "text", "DepartmentLoad();", true);
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function DepartmentLoad(){
            document.getElementById("lbSelectedDepartmentContacts").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("lbDepartmentContacts").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("txtDepartmentCategoryContactsFilter").disabled = true;
            ducument.getElementById("RadButton1").disabled = true;}
```

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in your browser console?

Comment: why don't you use C# code to disable the ListBoxes?

Comment: No im not getting any errors. i did  use the c# code for disabling the listBoxes but nothing is working

Answer (score 1):

**C# only approach to disable your 2 listboxes...**

Delete or comment out your existing `DisableControls()` method then add the following...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack) return;
    DisableControls();
}

private void DisableControls()
{
    lbSelectedDepartmentContacts.Enabled = lbDepartmentContacts.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generally:

- Use Sys.Application.Load to register your script. Calling the function earlier will cause problems with using the client-side API of the IScriptControls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx and http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/executing-javascript-code-from-server.
- use the API the Telerik control provides: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/listbox/client-side-programming/objects/radlistbox-object.

There seems to be no set_enabled() or set_disabled() method on the client (at least at the time of writing), so this seems to be impossible with JS, so you should go with the other answer that tells you to use server code.